# BOOL wrapper? Make an object of `BOOL` value. (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wrapper

How do I wrap a `BOOL` in an object type in Objective-C?

I want to store a `BOOL` in the `userInfo` object of an `NSTimer`. How do I wrap it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
NSNumber *boolForUserInfo = @YES; // or [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] the old way
[userInfo setObject:boolForUserInfo forKey:@"myBool"];
```

Retrieve with:

```
[[userInfo objectForKey:@"myBool"] boolValue];
```

Comment: As far as I know, your 'old way' is the best way to make an NSNumber from a BOOL if you're wrapping a variable and not a literal.

Comment: @JordanC you can use literal boxing syntax like `@(myScalarVar)` to make `NSNumber` from either simple `BOOL` or some `NSInteger`.